# Pandas pick top 10 values based on condition in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have written the below, which works to get the top 10 values from `ColA`.

`top10_contacts = df['ColA'].value_counts().head(10).index`

However, now I only want to pick the top 10 values from `ColA` for rows where value in `ColB` is False. So I wrote the below, but I get an error saying `ColA` - not sure what's the correct syntax, can someone please help?

`top10_contacts = df[df['ColB'] != True][df['ColA'].value_counts().head(10).index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC this is what you want:

```
df.loc[df.ColB == False, 'ColA'].value_counts().head(10).index
```

Or equivalently:

```
df.loc[~df.ColB, 'ColA'].value_counts().head(10).index
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Chipmunk_da I'm happy to help! :D

Comment: Is there a way to add another condition like: `df.loc[df.ColB == False && df.ColC != 'Unkown', 'ColA'].value_counts().head(10).index`? This code syntax I've written doesn't work. Says 'Invalid Syntax'

Comment: @Chipmunk_da try this: `df.loc[(df.ColB == False) & (df.ColC != 'Unkown'), 'ColA'].value_counts().head(10).index` (untested)

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chipmunk_da Nice!